# ng-animate not triggering animations

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, ng-animate

On my angular js site I have angular-animate lodaed and deployed (in the inspector I see angular-animate.js in the js folders so I know its loading. What I want to do is have my header animate on page load so I have added the following to my project

template.html

```
<header id="header" ng-animate=" 'animate' ">

 </header>
```

style.css

```
.animate-enter {
  -webkit-transition: 1s linear all; /* Chrome */
  transition: 1s linear all;
  opacity: 0;
}

.animate-enter.animate-enter-active {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

The issue being is no animation occurs when I click from the home link and load "template.html" Is there something I am missing here??

Answer (score 0):

As per the Angular documentation:

> The directives that support animation automatically are: ngRepeat,
>   ngInclude, ngIf, ngSwitch, ngShow, ngHide, ngView and ngClass. Custom
>   directives can take advantage of animation by using the $animate
>   service.

You need to use one of these directives in your header tag.

Comment: So would I just do `<header id="header" class="ng-class: animate ;">`

Comment: Your header needs to look something like this:

Comment: there was no example posted

Comment: Sorry, not sure what happened there.  The header should look something like this: <header id="header" ng-show="<some condition>" ng-class="'animate'"></header>  The animation will only fire when the directive's condition that is supporting the animation is toggled (in the example provided I'm using ng-show, but you can use any directive that supports animation as I mentioned above).